# BigInteger gcd value

Tags: java, biginteger, greatest-common-divisor

```
BigInteger n = BigInteger.valueOf(5);
BigInteger a = BigInteger.valueOf(3);
System.out.println(a.gcd(n) != BigInteger.ONE);
```

Why does this evaluate as `true` even though 5 and 3's gcd is 1?

Comment: @kai It's almost worse since BigInteger.ONE is a pre-initialized statically referenced object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use the `!=` operator, but instead use the `equals()` method

```
!(a.gcd(n).equals(BigInteger.ONE))
```

**Explanation:**

In Java, the `==` and `!=` operators, when used on objects, compare if the variables are references to the same exact object in memory, not if the objects have the same value. The `equals()` method checks if they have the same value.

Comment: Is there any explanation to that?

Comment: Added the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Since BigInteger is an object, you should rather use **equals**. You use **==** or **!=** to compare reference of the objects.

```
!(a.gcd(n).equals(BigInteger.ONE));
```